# Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

Tags: php, prestashop

alguien me podría ayudar, tengo mi página web de prestashop para mi tienda online, pero al realizar una actualización de la versión, he recibido este inconveniente en PHP:

Unknown error en línea 632 en archivo
public_html/modules/angarbanners/angarbanners.php
[8192] Unparenthesized `a ? b : c ? d : e` is deprecated. Use either `(a ? b : c) ? d : e` or `a ? b : (c ? d : e)`

El código es el siguiente:

```php
'context' => (Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE') == 0) ? 1 : ($this->context->shop->getTotalShops() != 1) ? $this->context->shop->getContext() : 1)
```

Y tengo una serie de errores de deprecated que están obsoletos, que no se si haya una manera más fácil de solucionarla.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te pide en este error es que lo pongas así seguramente:

```
'context' => (Configuration::get('PS_MULTISHOP_FEATURE_ACTIVE') == 0) ? 1 : (($this->context->shop->getTotalShops() != 1) ? $this->context->shop->getContext() : 1))
```

que desde mi punto de vista es la forma correcta de interpretar lo que habia antes sin ese paréntesis adicional que ahora te obligan a poner.

Prueba y nos cuentas.

Por otra parte, si has actualizado PHP te vas a encontrar muchos más fallos en otras partes inesperadas de tu código.

Cuando se actualiza a una nueva versión de PHP se debe también actualizar el código completo del PHP usado en ese servidor. En este caso sería actualizar Prestashop y todos sus módulos y código personalizado que le hayas puesto, lo cual puede ser una tarea ingente de trabajo y causar la caida del sitio web constantemente si no lo haces en un lugar aparte del de producción primero, y luego aplicas los cambios o realizas una migración completa de lo actualizado.

Si aún puedes volver a la versión anterior del PHP yo no me lo pensaría y tiraría atrás, y me montaria, en otro servidor, el escenario que quieres usar, y allí me pelearia con el prestashop hasta conseguir y estar seguro que todo funciona.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, si se solucionó el error después de hacerle los cambios, pero tengo la página caída con más problemas. Entonces voy a tomar tu solución para hacerlo todo fuera del espacio de producción y luego hacerle la migración completa. Gracias.

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido :-)  Si esta respuesta soluciona tu pregunta recuerda marcarla como aceptada para que la comunidad lo sepa y para que la pregunta no quede eternamente pendiente, gracias.  En [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo.